# Powershell Replace characters in substring

Tags: regex, powershell, csv

In formatting a CSV, I want to replace all the commas separating the values with the pipe character, which would be easy except I have a column of strings (have quotes around values) that occasionally has a comma in it.

How can I either replace all the commas with the pipe *except ones within quotes*?
OR, alternatively, how can I replace only pipe characters *inside quotes*? Since it's easy enough to change all the commas to pipes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always: use the right tool for the job. In this case the [`Import-Csv`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849891.aspx) and [`Export-Csv`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849932.aspx) cmdlets.

```psh
Import-Csv 'C:\input.csv' | Export-Csv 'C:\output.csv' -NoType -Delimiter '|'
```

Comment: And here I thought gasoline and a book of matches was the right tool for this job... I guess that only works for getting rid of spiders. Superb answer as usual Ansgar. Hopefully @Hesed will come back and mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thank you, @Ansger, that was it. It took me a little bit to get it to work, but I found out that Import-Csv cmdlet needed the file to be imported as a ".csv" file when used this way (I had previously saved it as a text file). So I just had to rearrange my lines.

Comment: @Hesed The extension doesn't matter, but the file must have the correct delimiter. By default both `Import-Csv` and `Export-Csv` assume a comma, which can be overridden via the `-Delimiter` parameter.